# Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist FirebaseFirestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

help pls I'm new for firebase, I want to get
field Widgetid name'name in
collectionName'Users'

(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).collection('Widget').snapshots() )

for get data from another collectionName 'Widget'

( FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Widget').doc(type).snapshots() )

to get real data, sorry I dont know how to
explain more , pls read a code make you understant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLUuP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4gEB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOMAf.jpg)

homepage()

```
    String type,

    final _widget = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection('Widget')
    .snapshots();
    final color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    final color1 = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
    final shadow = Theme.of(context).cardColor;
   return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        'Widget Menu',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      ),
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _widget,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return Container(
              height: 50*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
              child: ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                  return Card(
                    color: color1,
                    shadowColor: shadow,
                    elevation: 8,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 15*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Card(
                              color: color1,
                              elevation: 5,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:  document['image'] != null ?         
                                    (themeProvider.isDarkMode
                                    ? AssetImage('images/MainDark.png')
                                    : AssetImage('images/MainLight.png'))
                                    : NetworkImage(document['image']),
                              backgroundColor: color1,
                                minRadius: 50,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(document['name']),
                          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined),
                              onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              type = document['name'];
                              print(type);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          WidgetHome()));
                            });
                          })

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            );
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Widgethomepage()

```
             Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                            2 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier)),
                    color: color1,
                  ),
                  child: SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                              child: Text(type),
                              onPressed: (){
                                print(type);
                              },
                            ),
                            StreamBuilder(
                                stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Widget').doc(type).snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot1) {
                                  if(!snapshot1.hasData){return Align(alignment: 
                                    Alignment.center,child: Center(
                                    child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                                      color: color,
                                      size: 50.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  );
                                  }
                                  var id = snapshot1.data;
                                  return Container(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(id['name'],style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Card(
                                                shadowColor: shadow,
                                                elevation: 5,
                                                child: Container(
                                                  color: color1,
                                                  height: 30*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                                  width: 20*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier ,
                                                  child: Image(
                                                    image: NetworkImage(id['image']),),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            height:  45*SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                            color: Colors.yellow,
                                            child: id['Type']== 'test1'
                                                ? Test1() : (id['Type']=='test2' ? Test2() :  Align(alignment: Alignment.center,child: Center(
                                              child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                                                color: color,
                                                size: 50.0,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            ) ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      )
                                  );
                                }
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              HomePage()));
                                },
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 7,
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons
                                            .arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                                        size: 3.5 *
                                            SizeConfig
                                                .heightMultiplier,
                                        color: color,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "HomePage",
                                        style: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .headline5,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update how you get the fields from:

```dart
document['image']
```

to:

```dart
document.get('image')
```

or

```dart
document.data()['image']
```

From the [DocumentSnapshotPlatform documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/DocumentSnapshotPlatform-class.html)

> **DocumentSnapshotPlatform class**
>
> Contains data read from a document in your Firestore database.
> The data can be extracted by calling data() or by calling get() to get
> a specific field.

**Edit:**

It appears you're trying to use a non-existent document id in the line below:

```dart
stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Widget').doc(type).snapshots()
```

`type` should be replaced with the document id and not the `name` property of the object in the document which is what `type` stands for in the code snippet below(from your comment):

```dart
 type = document['name'];
```

Comment: In this line:                                 `stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Widget').doc(type).snapshots(),`, can you replace "type" with one of the ids from your database and see if the error still shows up?

Comment: type is a variable created, not available in firebase. :String type,

Comment: but I set variable, when I click it will change to that variable.

Comment: `IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined),
                              onPressed: (){
                            setState(() {
                              type = document['name'];
                              print(type);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          WidgetHome()));
                            });
                          })`

Comment: Looks like the type field does not exist on the database. You need to use an existing field.